# Flutter: change GestureRecognizers

Tags: flutter, gesture

I am using a PageView to implement an image gallery.  The currently displayed page can be zoomed by multi-fingered touch.

Everything works, except that the GestureRecognizer sometimes thinks the Scale gestures are `HorizontalDrag` gestures.

I would like to prioritize those gestures in the app so that the GestureRecognizer inside of the PageView wins.

Comment: To put it another way, I'd like to ensure that "HorizontalMultiDrag" is not used by the PageView and is used by my inner GestureRecogizer.  I see HorizontalMultiDragGestureRecognizer but great documentation on how to hook it up.  Maybe that's the class I need

Comment: I now have a modification to DragGestureRecognizer that "fixes" my specific issue.  
(It keeps track of pointers/fingers that are down, and if more than one is down, it rejects all gestures).  
If there is a way to inject this Recognizer, I'd be all set.